# Lazy<T> vs static ctor (prevent onbeforefieldinit)?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, static, lazy-evaluation

I have a DAL **base** class ( data access ) which has 2 members:

```
/*1*/    class BaseDal
/*2*/       {
/*3*/           static DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
/*4*/           static SqlDatabase sqlServerDB = factory.Create("ExampleDatabase") as SqlDatabase;
/*5*/       }
/*6*/   
/*7*/   
/*8*/   subclasses : 
/*9*/   
/*10*/    class MyCustomerDal:BaseDal
/*11*/       {
/*12*/          ...
/*13*/          ...
/*14*/          public static DataTable GetData()
/*15*/            {
/*16*/             // do something....
/*17*/            }
/*18*/   
/*19*/       }
/*20*/
```

My question is about lines 3,4.

*please notice that I don't create `new MyCustomerDal` cuz I dont need an instance but only to use the method `GetData()` (`static`).Also , those 2 lines can serve all derived classes.*

And here is my question :

I want those 2 initializers (line 3,4) to be laze initialize.

well I have 2 options :

**option 1**

I can set a static ctor which basically means that those members will be running only when the class is accessed ( `beforefieldinit` issue).

**option 2**

I could use `Lazy` :(+property)

```
/*1*/   Lazy<SqlDatabase> myDb = new Lazy<SqlDatabase>(() => factory.Create("ExampleDatabase") as SqlDatabase);
/*2*/   
/*3*/           protected SqlDatabase Mydb 
/*4*/           {
/*5*/               get { return myDb.Value; }
/*6*/           }
```

But to tell you the truth I don't know which approach is better....

Comment: you've probably seen this or know but just in case have a look at this article http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx

Comment: I wouldnt be writing this question without knowing about the beforefieldinit traps.... :-)

Comment: ok sorry,my last shoot :),last example in this article http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `static Lazy<T>` fields (optionally with added static properties to access the lazy values, as you have).

This way, you can use them without needing an instance and also have the fully lazy behavior.

Your option 1 will initialize both fields as soon as you access one of them, which probably is not desirable.

Comment: I still will need the static cTOR though , becuase we still do `new Lazy(something)`.... this way it will be fully full :-).....p.s. insureInitialize solve this issue.

Comment: you want to lazily initialize the `Lazy<T>` objects?

Comment: Yes I do. creating Lazy Object requires new Lazy() which should also be lazy. Read about `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized<T> Method` which solves this problem. ( or adding static ctor here - will do the same trick).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't looked at LazyInitializer closely. Note that if you use a static `Lazy<T>`, that inherently handles the multi threading issues. With `LazyInitializer`, you should use the overload that takes a `ref bool initialized` so that you don't wastefully initialize multiple objects. Overall, I'd go with `Lazy<T>` because of simplicity, and because the overhead of a single 'Lazy<T>` is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on your comment

I recommend you to read [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C# (by Jon Skeet)](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) and his article [C# and beforefieldinit](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx).

It seems like the best approach in your case is also the most explicit. Use Lazy<**T**>.

Your first approach is worse. [ECMA-335 6th Edition / June 2012 (Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) Partitions I to VI, p. 43-44)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf):

> 3: If marked BeforeFieldInit then the type’s initializer method is executed at, or  sometime before, first access to any static field
> defined for that type.
>
> 4: If not marked BeforeFieldInit then that type’s initializer method is executed at (i.e.,  is triggered by):
>
> a. first access to any static field of that type, or
>
> b. first invocation of any static method of that type, or
>
> c. first invocation of any instance or virtual method of that type if it is a value  type or
>
> d. first invocation of any constructor for that type.

Hence, using Lazy<**T**> is better than your first approach both if the type is marked BeforeFieldInit or isn't marked BeforeFieldInit.

Comment: I don't see how it different from my option 1. and BDW , his last sample  does use LAZY. and this sample is not very useful if you have other static fields. cuz if you touch the others , those(which we talk about) will be auto fill. and we don't want that.